# Elasticsearch geo_point search exception

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a little problem with geo_point filter in my mapping.

mapping:
`offer: ...
               mapping: ...
                    location:
                            type: nested
                            include_in_parent: true
                            properties:
                                city:
                                    type: string
                                    analyzer: my_analyzer
                                    boost: 0.5
                                    include_in_all: true
                                region:
                                    type: string
                                    analyzer: my_analyzer
                                    boost: 0.3
                                    include_in_all: false
                                geo:
                                    type: geo_point
                                    lat_lon: true
                                    boost: 0
                                    include_in_all: false`

When execute this code:

```
        $filter = new Filter\BoolOr();

        $geo = new Filter\Nested();
        $geo->setPath('offer.location');
        $geo->setFilter(
            new Filter\GeoDistance('location.geo', array(
                'lat' => $city->getLatitude(),
                'lon' => $city->getLongitude()
            ), sprintf('%dkm', $distance))
        );
        $filter->addFilter($geo);
```

I get this exeption:

> nested: QueryParsingException[[index] failed to find geo_point field [location.geo]];

Comment: Shouldn't it be `offer.location.geo`?